# SWIG and Mingw-64 to use with Python … not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, c++, c, dll, 64-bit

I want to use Swig to use my C/C++ "model-controler" application with Python HMI.

I first test python swig simple example on my ubuntu PC and it works like a charm.

Then I tried to do the same on a Win7-64bits with Mingw-64:
"Wrap" by using

```
swig.exe -python path_to_swig_examples\python\simple\example
```

in cmd window, it's generate example_wrap.c… Ok

Then compile under mingw terminal (personally I launch by right-click in explorer then *Git Bash here*)

```
gcc -c -fPIC -DWIN32 example.c example_wrap.c -I/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Python36-32/include
```

generate my objs…Ok
and link

```
ld -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.dll
```

and I have many `undefined reference`

```
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `strlen'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x1de): undefined reference to `strcmp'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x5ff): undefined reference to `strcmp'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x957): undefined reference to `strlen'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x98f): undefined reference to `strcpy'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x9c8): undefined reference to `strcmp'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xa38): undefined reference to `strlen'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xaaf): undefined reference to `strncpy'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xaf5): undefined reference to `strcmp'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xb11): undefined reference to `memset'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xb57): undefined reference to `__imp_PyUnicode_AsUTF8String'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xb76): undefined reference to `__imp_PyBytes_AsStringAndSize'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xb88): undefined reference to `malloc'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xbaa): undefined reference to `memcpy'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xc15): undefined reference to `__imp_PyUnicode_FromString'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xc69): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_MemoryError'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xc7c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IOError'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xc8f): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xca2): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added link to python36.dll (based on Anaconda3: https://www.continuum.io/downloads)  `/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python36.dll`:

```
ld -shared example.o example_wrap.o /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python36.dll -o _example.dll
```

and python undefined msgs disappeared… but I have still C/C++ functions `undefined reference` …
…

```
ld -shared example.o example_wrap.o /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python36.dll /c/Windows/System32/msvcr120.dll -o _example.dll
```

and dll was created !

Thanks for [is all the available swig+python+mingw compile information outdated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860109/is-all-the-available-swigpythonmingw-compile-information-outdated)

… dll was created but doesn't works:
`"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_example' "`

[swig no module named _example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095083/swig-no-module-named-example)
then rename dll to pyd…
`ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`
…was because it is python in 32 bits I ran.

Launch anaconda python:

```
C:\Program Data\Anaconda3\python.exe
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)…
>>> import example
>>> example.gcd(42,36)
6
>>> example.cvar.Foo
3.0
```

finally, it works… after much time spent !

Versions:
Windows 7 sp1
Swig 3.0.12
MingW-64
Anaconda3 4.4.0
gcc 6.2.0 / ld 2.25